# Direct X drivers for ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I am trying to play my new Luxor game under Ubuntu linux but a message comes up saying I am missing the Direct X 3d driver.  Where do I find this and how do I install it to be able to play my game.

Comment: Is this a Windows game?

Answer (score 2):

> Where do I find this

You will not find these for Ubuntu/Linux. DirectX is a proprietary set of APIs, owned by Microsoft and they have not and probably will never release a version for Ubuntu/Linux.

> and how do I install it to be able to play my game.

Luxor can be played with [WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22692) with a platinum and 2 silver ratings. Installaton of DX on WINE is tricky but there are some [guides](http://www.dedoimedo.com/games/wine-directx.html).

As with anything related with Microsoft: if you want to play Windows games and have an experience as intended by the creators of those games install Windows. Either as a dual boot or in a VirtualBox container.